# sed regex to match exact pattern and ignore some pattern

Tags: linux, sed, yaml

I have a YML, in which I need to append numeric with double quotes. I tried various regex but somehow it gets break somewhere or other. I need to avoid alphanum or alpha...

```
- name: HEALTH_ELASTIC_HOST 
  value: 40c07d4283d245.elastic.test.com
- name: HEALTH_ELASTIC_PORT
  value: 9243
- name: HEALTH_ELASTIC_USERNAME
  value: elastic
```

The basic cmd which I took, and modified

```
sed 's/[0-9]*[0-9]/"&"/g' values.yaml
```

Expected Result

```
- name: HEALTH_ELASTIC_HOST 
  value: 40c07d4283d245.elastic.test.com
- name: HEALTH_ELASTIC_PORT
  value: "9243"
- name: HEALTH_ELASTIC_USERNAME
  value: elastic
```

Any help is appreciated..link to any doc or cmd.

Comment: Could you please post expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```bash
sed -E 's/([: ]+)([0-9]+) *$/\1"\2"/' file.yml

- name: HEALTH_ELASTIC_HOST
  value: 40c07d4283d245.elastic.test.com
- name: HEALTH_ELASTIC_PORT
  value: "9243"
- name: HEALTH_ELASTIC_USERNAME
  value: elastic
```

**Explanation:**

- `([: ]+)`: Match 1+ of `:` or space and capture in group #2
- `([0-9]+)`: Match 1+ digits an capture in group #2
- `*`: Match 0 or more spaces
- `$`: match end position
- `\1"\2"`: In substitution we wrap back-reference #2 with double quotes

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following(experts advise to use yq like tools to edit yaml since OP is using `sed` here so going with it).

```
sed -E 's/(^[[:space:]]+value: )([0-9]+$)/\1"\2"/g' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, Using `sed`'s `-E` option to enable ERE(extended regular expressions) then in main program using regex `(^[[:space:]]+value: )([0-9]+$)` along with substitute option of `sed`. Regex(`(^[[:space:]]+value: )([0-9]+$)`) will create 2 capturing groups, where 1st one will have values like:  `value:` in it and 2nd capturing group will have digits in it.

Then while performing substitution simply substituting it with 1st capturing group followed by `"` and 2nd capturing group followed by `"` as per requirement.

Comment: Thanks it worked, unable to Mark both the answers

Comment: @Aman, yeah you can mark only one. I leave up to you to choose which one you want to select, keep posting Good Q & As on this great site, cheers.